# AEM Metadata Schema Editor Form doesn't show Asset Rating field

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm creating new fields to customize the Assets Metadata Schema, however, there is a field missing: Asset Rating. Looking into the web I've figured out that is disabled on `.jsp` configuration file, so, I've enabled that (uncommenting) directly in CRX repository. However, after trying this approach the field keeps missing on the form

[image]
[image]

Obs.: I don't what means that comment

`<!-- CQ-4284633 Disable ratings component in metaschema editor when skyline is enabled -->`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using AEM as a Cloud Service? If so, the Asset Ratings widget is not supported in the schema editor.

From the feature parity section of the [AEM Assets Cloud notable changes.](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/assets/assets-cloud-changes.html?lang=en#cloud-service-feature-status)

[image]